# Where to find express.js settings

Tags: node.js, express

I'm almost ashamed to ask this, but where can I find information about the settings for express.js? According to the documentation I can use `app.set(name, setting)` to assign setting `name` to `setting`, however I can't find anywhere which settings there are and how they work.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings

Comment: @James - Thanks, I overlooked that!

Comment: @JamesAllardice Why not add that as an answer so Tiddo can accept it.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell - Well I didn't add it as an answer because link-only answers are frowned upon (the URL may change, for example, rendering the answer useless). However, in this case you're probably right so I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here:

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings

> **settings**
>
> The following settings are provided to alter how Express will behave:
>
> - `env` Environment mode, defaults to process.env.NODE_ENV or "development"
> - `trust proxy` Enables reverse proxy support, disabled by default
> - `jsonp callback name` Changes the default callback name of ?callback=
> - `json replacer` JSON replacer callback, null by default
> - `json spaces` JSON response spaces for formatting, defaults to 2 in development, 0 in production
> - `case sensitive routing` Enable case sensitivity, disabled by default, treating "/Foo" and "/foo" as the same
> - `strict routing` Enable strict routing, by default "/foo" and "/foo/" are treated the same by the router
> - `view cache` Enables view template compilation caching, enabled in production by default
> - `view engine` The default engine extension to use when omitted
> - `views` The view directory path

Comment: `app.set('strict routing', true);`